# TDengine windows python connector run examples

Tags: python, connector, tdengine

I'm a freshman from python, and I want to use TDengine's python connector to connect with the TDengine cluster. I followed the instruction from the website [taos connector](https://www.taosdata.com/en/documentation/connector) of  to install prepare the dev-environment.
The follow process are the steps that I did:

- install python version Python 3.7.9
- copy the file "C:\TDengine\driver\taos.dll" to the "C:\ windows\ system32"
- tried to run the follow command in cmd

> ```
> cd C:\TDengine\connector\python
> python -m pip install .
> ```

but there is not pip on my windows , i follow  the other instructor that:

- If there is no pip command on the machine, the user can copy the taos
  folder under src/connector/python to the application directory for
  use.
  After this I just RUN checker, to see if the connector is available.

> cd {install_directory}/examples/python/PYTHONConnectorChecker/

> python3 PythonChecker.py -host

But I didn't get any out put, it should output some information to indicate that the connector is available or not. But i didn't get any information. Does anyone can help install this connector and run this checker?

Answer (score 0):

Python3.4+ has a builtin `ensurepip` module to install pip:

```sh
python -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

And the install the connector with:

```sh
pip install -U taospy
```

Now you can run the checker.